# @EJB inject does not work when you have interface inheritance

Tags: ejb, wildfly

I have the following code.

```
public interface Multiplier {

    void multiply();
}

@Local
public interface MultiplierLocal extends Multiplier{
}

@Remote
public interface MultiplierRemote extends Multiplier {
}

@Stateless
public class MultiplierImpl implements MultiplierLocal,MultiplierRemote{
    @Override
    public void multiply() {
        System.out.println(" called multiplier ");
    }
}
```

Now when I inject this EJB like below into another ejb, it does not work. But it works when I have the Local interface type.

```
@Stateless
public class AdderImpl implements AdderLocal,AdderRemote {

    // This does not work.
    @EJB
    Multiplier mul;

    // This works.
    /*@EJB
    MultiplierLocal mul;*/

    @Override
    public void add() {
        System.out.println(" Adder Imple called");
        mul.multiply();
    }
}
```

The error I get is in wildfly13.

> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type
>   'com.libin.ejb.Multiplier' for binding com.libin.ejb.AdderImpl/mul

All the EJB examples that I see does not have a base interface which is extended by local and remote interfaces. Is there a way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `@Remote` interfaces is to define all methods that can be invoked by a "remote client", while an `@Local` interface can have more methods that maybe used only inside the same application. This means that your `@Local` interface normally extends your `@Remote` interface. Hence, you inheritance hierarchy should look like this:

```
@Remote
public interface Multiplier {

    void multiply();
}

@Local
public interface MultiplierLocal extends Multiplier{
}

@Stateless
public class MultiplierBean implements MultiplierLocal {

    @Override
    public void multiply() {
        System.out.println(" called multiplier ");
    }
}
```

In this case you can inject `Multiplier`, because it is a valid EJB interface.

Having an additional interface above the `@Remote` interface does not make much sense.

Additionally, you can also omit the `MultiplierLocal` interface, because it does not offer any value and the EJB spec says, that all public methods of a bean are automatically local. Hence, no need to specify an additional `@Local` interface.